# How can you access code behind a web page?

Tags: javascript, html

So on your page right now, you can see up the top your username, points and badges... Using something like firebug, you can see the HTML that shows `<a class="profile-link" href="/users/userid/username">Username</a>` for example, but is there anyway to view the code that actually made that be displayed in the HTML?

I mean javascript or whatever was used to process that. Basically there are some websites that i would like to know how they do things similar to this.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can see the JavaScript the page uses, but the things you describe are very rarely displayed using JavaScript.

Comment: you can view the client side javascript, but not the server side code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is javascript in a webpage, then you watch the code directly in the source. But if its written in JSP or PHP. There is no way you can watch the code, without having access to the webserver.

I think it is a bit of security to the webpages.

Comment: Thanks :D Disappointing, but glad to know i can stop searching uselessly now ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how they are implemented. In this case, no. Because the name, for example, would be inserted into the HTML whilst still on stackoverflow's servers, the only way to see that code would be to hack into the site. Not advisable.